# Apple Watch CFBundleName accessibility readout

Tags: accessibility, apple-watch

In my Apple Watch App, the name of the App contains letters that should be read out separately in the Apple Watch companion app when accessibility is on. 
eg. the name is like "SampleAppName AT" and the readout says "at" instead of "A" "T" separately

However, since the companion app shows the name from the CFBundleName of the iPhone app, it reads out incorrectly.

In the case of the iPhone app putting the the Unicode Hex Character Code "&#x7f;" between the letters eg. "SampleAppName A&#x7f;T" in the CFBundleDisplayName solved the issue of readout for the iPhone app.

I've tried putting in the Unicode Hex Character Code &#x7f; between the letters for the CFBundleName but that does not solve the issue. Also I'm not too sure if that is the right way to go for the CFBundleName.

Suggestions on solving this are welcome.